# How to connect to a udp port command line?

Tags: udp

This is what I tried,but seems not working :

```
[root@ ~]# netstat -a|grep 48772
udp        0      0 *:48772                     *:*                                     
[root@ ~]# telnet localhost 48772
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use netcat instead:

`nc -u localhost 48772`

Answer (score 18):

You need to use [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) instead, telnet only supports tcp.  Something like this will work:

```
$ nc -u localhost 48772
```

netcat is installed by default on most modern linux machines (assuming that's what you have).

Also for completeness sake I want to point out that there's another tool called [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) which describes itself as 'netcat++'.  Might be a good thing to check out.  In general however netcat will do what you need just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/):

```
$ socat - UDP:localhost:48772
```

which connects its standard input to port 48772 on `localhost`.

Conversely, to set up a server listening on UDP port 48772 that outputs to standard output:

```
$ socat UDP-RECV:48772 STDOUT
```

If the port is below 1024 then you need to run the listener as `root` or use `sudo`. [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) can act as a relay (actually its primary purpose) where it accepts input on one port and outputs to another. Definately *netcat++*.